# "Content-Disposition" is not working

Tags: java

I want't excel Download.
But, download screen does not appear.
Did not occur error in the source.

Why does not it work?

Thank you.

code:

```
        String destFileName = "TEST.xls";

        StringBuffer contentDisposition = new StringBuffer();
        contentDisposition.append("attachment;fileName=\"");
        contentDisposition.append(new String(destFileName.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1"));
        contentDisposition.append("\"");


        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.toString());
        //response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.toString());
        //response.setContentType("application/x-msexcel");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the HTTP response headers your client received. Are they as you intend them to be?

Comment: Sorry, I can't  understand Your answer. What include the HTTP response headers client received?

Comment: Your browser is a HTTP client. It makes a request for an URL, the server returns a HTTP response. This response contains HTTP headers. Please check that these headers contain the `Content-Disposition` header as you set it.

Comment: I found solution. It works when I use ajaxSubmit instead of ajax / json when calling jsp

Answer (score 1):

filename token should be in lowercase as specified in the RFC:

```
19.5.1 Content-Disposition

        content-disposition = "Content-Disposition" ":"
                              disposition-type *( ";" disposition-parm )
        disposition-type = "attachment" | disp-extension-token
        disposition-parm = filename-parm | disp-extension-parm
        filename-parm = "filename" "=" quoted-string
        disp-extension-token = token
        disp-extension-parm = token "=" ( token | quoted-string )
```

=>  contentDisposition.append("attachment; **filename**=...");

Comment: I found solution. 
It works when I use ajaxSubmit instead of ajax / json when calling jsp.